# Python loop over files in directory then list

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop over files in a directory and list the path of each one.
My code iterates over each file but lists the wrong directory. What am I missing to return the full directory?

Here's my code so far:

```
import os

directory = "posts/"

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".md"):
        dir = os.path.abspath(file)
        print "The Path is: " + str(dir)
```

The structure is like this:

```
.
├── app.py
└── posts
    ├── first.md
    └── second.md
```

Output from the terminal (missing the `/posts/` part of the directory):

```
The Path is: /home/tc/user/python-md-reader/second.md
The Path is: /home/tc/user/python-md-reader/first.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the directory back into the path:

```
dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, file))
```

Comment: This solves my immediate problem thanks. I'm unsure why the abspath method returns the root of my app.py file instead of the posts directory though

Comment: @c4binever: I think you thought `abspath` would "find a file" but actually it just takes the path you give it and "expands" it relative to the current directory.  Since your current directory is `.` and not `./directory`, it didn't do what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the source code:

```
def abspath(path):
    """Return the absolute version of a path."""
    if not isabs(path):
        if isinstance(path, unicode):
            cwd = os.getcwdu()
        else:
            cwd = os.getcwd()
        path = join(cwd, path)
    return normpath(path)         # normpath according to the comment 
                                  # """Normalize path, eliminating double slashes, etc."""
```

What `abspath` does is simply join the current working directory with the `path` you provided, since you only provide the file as a path, and you are one level up of the `posts` directory it will get ignored.